Why do I get this warning Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Events[]'.ts(2322)?
I've been having a difficult time to figure out where is this warning coming from. So I'm following shadCN's tutorial regarding Datatable, so after finishing it, I tried creating my own table wherein I'm fetching my data from the database. But after finishing it, I get this warning from TypeScript
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Events[]'.ts(2322)

So what I did is I created an interface props.
export interface Events {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  email: string;
  fullName: string;
  contactPerson: string;
  department: string;
  status: "PENDING" | "SUCCESS";

  dateOfEvent: string;
  startingTime: string;
  endingTime: string;

  purpose: string;

  doesHaveDryRun: string;
  dryRunDate?: string; // Optional
  dryRunStart?: string; // Optional
  dryRunEnd?: string; // Optional

  doesHaveTCETAssitance: string[];
  tcetOtherAssitance?: string; // Optional

  meetingTypeOption: "meeting" | "webinar" | "hybrid" | "documentation";
  meetingTypeServices: string[];
  meetingTypeServiceLink?: string; // Optional
  cameraSetup?: string; // Optional
}

And then I used it to for my to call my data
export const getData = async () => {
    try {
        const data: Events[] = await db.appoinmentSchedule.findMany()

        return data
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
}

This is my zod schema
const formSchemaData = z.object({
    title: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "title must be at least 2 characters.",
    }),
    email: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "email must be at least 2 characters.",
    }).email(),
    fullName: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "The person who requested the event",
    }),
    contactPerson: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "Contact Person / Event Handler"
    }),
    department: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "department  must be at least 2 characters.",
    }),
  
  
    // set 2 
    dateOfEvent: z.string(), // Assuming dateOfEvent is a string in the desired format
    startingTime: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "staring time must be set.",
    }),
    endingTime: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "ending time must be set.",
    }),
  
    purpose: z.string().min(2,{
      message: "Please choose a purpose of the meeting.",
    }),
  
    // Set 3
    doesHaveDryRun:  z.enum(["yes", "no"], {
      required_error: "Please select if yes or not"
    }),
    dryRunDate: z.string().optional(),
    dryRunStart: z.string().optional(),
    dryRunEnd: z.string().optional(),

    doesHaveTCETAssitance: z.array(z.string()).refine((value) => value.some((item) => item), {
      message: 'Please select at lease on the option'
    }),
    tcetOtherAssitance: z.string().optional(),

    //set 4
    meetingTypeOption: z.enum(['meeting','webinar','hybrid','documentation']),
    meetingTypeServices: z.array(z.string()).refine((value) => value.some((item) => item), {
      message: 'Please select at lease on the option'
    }),
    meetingTypeServiceLink: z.string().optional(),
    cameraSetup: z.string().optional(),
    
  })

This is my schema.prisma
model AppoinmentSchedule {
  id String @id @default(cuid())
  title String
  email String
  fullName String
  contactPerson String
  department String
  dateOfEvent String
  startingTime String
  endingTime String
  purpose String
  doesHaveDryRun String
  dryRunDate String?
  dryRunStart String?
  dryRunEnd String?
  doesHaveTCETAssitance String
  tcetOtherAssitance String?
  meetingTypeOption String
  meetingTypeServices String
  meetingTypeServiceLink String?
  cameraSetup String?
  status AppointmentStatus @default(PENDING)

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt 
}


You define the same type twice: as a Typescript interface Events and as a zod schema. You could infer a type from a zod schema: type Event = z.infer<typeof formSchemaData>.
Also, you don't need to specify a type explicitly here:
`
const data: Events[] = await db.appoinmentSchedule.findMany()
// you could
const data = await db.appoinmentSchedule.findMany()
sincedb.appoinmentSchedule.findMany()` should be typed and return the correct type.
